# I want to get all audio form device

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I want to get all the audio from device to my application to make a app which play audio.
I see an example on on_audio_query that work fine in in example but when i try myself it doesnot work. I try so many solution but cannot identify why error happened.

Actually the problem is the permosson window cannot pop up.

i am used
on_audio_query
permisson handler

add permision from main AndoroidManifest.file
and also call to show permisson windows for get user permisson.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

```
here is my code to open permisson window 

Future<bool> requestPermission([OnAudioQuery? audioQuery]) async {
  var ans = false.obs;
  print('working on audio query');
  var c = await audioQuery!.checkAndRequest(
    retryRequest: false,
  );
  ans.value = c;
  if (ans.value == false) {
    await Permission.storage.request();
    // openAppSettings();
    print('working on audio query 33');
  }
  print('the ans is $c');

  return ans.value;
}
```

I try so many many solution but cannot solve this problem ..[mobile cannot open the permisson window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HapB.png)

Answer (score 1):

You should look up the Flutter package [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) as it has some information in the package description that will help you with this error.

> On Android the `Permission.storage` permission is linked to the Android `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions. Starting from Android SDK 29 (Android 10) the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permissions have been marked deprecated and have been fully removed/ disabled since Android SDK 33 (Android 13).

Regarding Audio recording, you should know that it's not currently possible to record audio from other apps unless they allow it specifically, but you can record audio from your own app, if that is what you need.